# Azure Marketplace and IronMQ unable to purchase

Tags: azure, ironmq, azure-marketplace

I'm following along with these instructions http://dev.iron.io/worker/azure/ and I keep getting a generic error that it didn't complete. Has anyone tried this recently and gotten it to work? I tried the first time last week and again today.

Thank you.
Edit with error message:
Your purchase of the application and service IronMQ cannot be completed at this time. Please try again later. Could not create your application and service. (Internal Server Error).

Comment: That is mine for now : `We cannot provide a billing estimate at this time. Please try again later. If this error persists, contact support with the following information.`.. dunno why !

Comment: You should post your code and error message exactly to get better answers

Comment: @ste-fu: you're right. Updated, thank you.